# Analyze and archive incoming messages to filesystem

Tags: email

Where I work we're trying to create a mailbox where our employees sends messages to it and the mail server processess them. Much like the Support of some companies where you send an email a ticket is automatically opened, but instead we need to save the messages to the filesystem depending upon an identified ID in the message.

We're considering two options:

#### 1) Identify by `to:` header

Messages are sent to `12345@domain.com` or `os+12345@domain.com`, where **12345** is out customer identifier, and the mail server processess messages and saves them to:

/data/os/**12345**/Customer contact.eml

#### 2) Identify by `subject:` header

Messages are sent to `os@domain.com` and the customer identifier is specified in the subject `[12345] Customer contact`.

We need to do some other verifications as the user (`from:` header) is authorized to archive messages to that customer, but this is another story.

I tried searching for something along the line of AMaViS and ClamAV filters but had no success.

Do you have any clues on how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: sorry, I forgot to mention that our mail server is postfix.

Comment: what mail server?

Comment: @Ward sorry, I forgot to mention... edited.

Comment: People, please care to explain why the downvotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  A mail filtering tool like `procmail` could be made to do what you're asking, but it would be just as easy to write a small application in your favorite language that would parse an incoming message and execute whatever actions you deemed appropriate.

Postfix -- and most other Unix mailer software -- makes it very easy to forward email to a certain address to a program of your choice.  A combination of a service entry in `master.cf` and a tranport map `transport` will probably get you what you want.

You could also just install some ticket handling software, for which there are many open source options.